# Is there R/Python function for find the best sample combination for regression model?

Tags: python, r, regression

I have 100 sample data, from there I want to find a regression model that fulfills all the classical assumptions using only the 50 sample data. How do I make the loop program determine the best sample combination from the initial 100 data samples for a regression model that follows the classical assumptions? (Using R or Python)

I hope to get the best 50 samples for my model

Comment: Tried panda?....

Comment: I have tried to manually create a regression model by determining a combination of 50 samples using simple random sampling, but all the models I have made have not met the residual assumptions.

Comment: I don’t know of a function that does this. But more importantly, cherry-picking cases that match certain assumptions is going to lead, by definition, to a subsample that isn’t representative of your data. It would be better to select a model that fits the characteristics of your data than to try to force your data to fit your model. For instance, a glm or non-parametric model rather than a linear model. [stats.se] may be able to help identify an appropriate model if you provide more details about your data.